# C++ vector, erase don't understand

Tags: c++, vector, assertion

Hi in my project that's roguelike RPG im using vector to keep polymorphic indicators to all monsters, parts of abstract class Mob. The problem is during fight - there's a function that return iterator selecting nob that we are attacking(i skipped for tests that in case here's no monster it returns begin of vector).

```
   vector<Mob*>::iterator Hero::TryAttack(vector <Mob*> monsters)
{
    int trying_x = pos_x, trying_y = pos_y;
    switch (DIR)
    {
        case UP: trying_y--;
        case DOWN: trying_y++;
        case LEFT: trying_x--;
        case RIGHT: trying_x++;
    }

    if (!monsters.empty())
    {
        for (vector <Mob*>::iterator i = monsters.begin(); i != monsters.end(); i++)
        {
            if ((*i)->pos_x == trying_x && (*i)->pos_y == trying_y)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }

    return monsters.begin();
}
```

and when i calling that function here:

```
switch (hero.CheckAction())
        {
            case ATTACK:
            {
                //delete rat3;
                if(!monsters.empty()) 
                    monsters.erase(hero.TryAttack(monsters));

                test_map.Draw(monsters, NPCs);
                break;
            }
            default: break;
        }
```

there's poping assertion failure: 
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FIVq.png)

i understand that erase returns next element after deleted but how can i delete that only one existing element in vector?

Comment: When `monsters.empty()` you return `monsters.begin()`, which happens to coincide with `monsters.end()`.

Comment: @user58697,  no, `!monsters.empty()` check before call ensures it doesn't.

Comment: @yurikilochek `!monsters.empty()` only protects the loop. I am talking about `return monsters.begin()` at the end of `TryAttack`. An attempt to erase it is fatal, if monsters are empty.

Comment: Why do you return `monsters.begin()` if a monster is not found? The typical thing to do would be to return `monsters.end()`.

Comment: @user58697, `!monsters.empty()` *before call* to `hero.TryAttack(monsters)`. In there, `monsters` is never empty, thus `monsters.begin() != monsters.end()`

Comment: @Galik i wrote in comment that's it simplification for tests

Answer (score 0):

```
Hero::TryAttack(vector <Mob*> monsters)
```

You are passing `monsters` by value. Returned iterator refers to nonexistent copy of the vector. Pass it by reference:

```
Hero::TryAttack(vector <Mob*>& monsters)
```

Comment: @KarolDrach what doesn't?

Comment: same problem occurs. in other forum someone advice me to use

Comment: if(!monsters.empty()) 
{
                    auto it = hero.TryAttack(monsters);
                    if(it != monsters.end())
                    monsters.erase();
}

Comment: and it's not crashing, but working a bit weird, i need to research it deeper :D